# git status show files between ""

Tags: git, git-status

I made git status command and get this:

```
#   "public/images/wallpaper/wait/1920\321\2051080.jpg"
#   public/style.css
```

Why some files are between quotes? And how I can add to .gitignore them?

Comment: You have unusual "\" sign in your file name.

Comment: @klm123 It's not a backslash in the file name, it's two characters (octal 321 followed by octal 205) that don't have a printable representation in the current locale...

Comment: @twalberg, I think so. That's russian language files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are shown between quotes because the file name contains backslashes. In the shell, backslashes have a special meaning, so you have to either escape them or quote them.

The quotes are a convenience so you can just copy and paste git status's output, e.g., to add the file to the index:

```
$ git add "public/images/wallpaper/wait/1920\321\2051080.jpg"
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ copied and pasted
```

You can just add the filename to .gitignore without the quotes. Most probably, you'll want to add something like this to your .gitignore file:

```
public/images/wallpaper/wait/*.jpg
```